# passing argument to the url in django

Tags: python, django

## in views.py

```
def parts_home(request):
    part_list_= models.part_list.objects.all()
    gly_name = ['glyphicon glyphicon-plus', 'glyphicon glyphicon-log-out']
    link_list = ['parts:part_add', 'main:login_page']
    link_name = ['Add Part', 'Log Out']
    my_list = zip(gly_name, link_list, link_name)
    return render(request,'parts.html',{'part_list':part_list_,'my_list':my_list})
```

in template

```
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      {% for i,j,k in my_list %}
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="{% url j %}" class="nav-link"><span class="{{ i }}"></span>{{k}} </a> </li>
      {% endfor %}
     </ul>
```

URL pattern

```
 url(r'^(?P<login_status>[0,1])/$',views.login_page,name='login_page')
```

Another url directly mapped but 'login_page' needs argument how can I pass an argument through my views.py to the template so that 'login_page' is mapped?
or is there any way to do so?
basically, i have created a navigation bar base template and for each page, i passed the names and link to the template so that I can use the same navigation bar in all of my pages  by passing arguments to the {% include 'template name ' with my_list=my_list%},is it a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an if statement and pass the argument to the url tag depending on whether it exists.

```
{% if url_arg %}{% url j url_arg %}{% else %}{% url j %}
```

However this approach is ugly, and would break as soon as you had a URL pattern with two arguments.

I would recommend reversing the url in the view rather than the template:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def parts_home(request):
    gly_name = ['glyphicon glyphicon-plus', 'glyphicon glyphicon-log-out']
    link_list = [reverse('parts:part_add'), reverse('main:login_page', args=[login_status])]
    link_name = ['Add Part', 'Log Out']
```

Then change the template to:

```
  {% for i,j,k in my_list %}
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="{{ j }}" class="nav-link"><span class="{{ i }}"></span>{{k}} </a> </li>
  {% endfor %}
```

Note the template would be more readable if you used `{% for class,url,text in my_list %}`

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Thanx for help anyway

Comment: It seems an ok approach. If you need to display the navigation bar on multiple pages, then you might want to create a [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext).

Comment: I want to use the my_list variable on the all the templates but it will have different values for different pages but using context processor using two values for same variable name won't it be over written?

Comment: If `my_list` is different on different views, then a context processor might not be suitable.

Comment: what are other approaches then? to build a navigation bar and use it on all the pages. or developers make different navigation on the different web pages of the same website?

Comment: That's getting off topic for this answer.